# delphi 10.3.1 / android 8.1 how to prevent closing the app while in background

Tags: android, delphi, service

the app uses an Indy http server in order to respond to requests or to send infos to the client(s).
I need the app running always targeting Oreo 8.1+.

Because of limiting background [services in Oreo](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background), how can be this task achieved with delphi in the given conditions?

The app should also has a mini UI in order to control the connected clients. (in case the info is valuable for design considerations)

I tried this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mD3WLK8FYc) and is working fine until Oreo, but it doesn't help me in my case.
It would also helps if you guide me to adapt this working example for Oreo 8.1+

Comment: Using foreground service is the only way I know which keeps the app running

Comment: Any hints where I can find Delphi examples? For Java there are a lot...

Comment: There's a demo here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/AndroidLocation that includes moving the service into the foreground when the app goes into the background. Note that the demo relies on other units in the Kastri Free library